# fancybox close button disappearing after minifying fancybox css

Tags: css, fancybox, minify

so I'm using fancybox, as well as Google's minify http://code.google.com/p/minify/

but then after minifying the fancybox css, when I click on something that is fancyboxed, the close button on the fancybox disappears from it...

I checked the minified css source code, and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the close property:

```
#fancybox-close{position:absolute;top: -15px;right: -15px;width:30px;height:30px;background:transparent url('/jqui/plugins/fancybox/fancybox/fancybox.png') -40px 0px;cursor:pointer;z-index:1103;display:none}
```

versus the normal version

```
#fancybox-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    right: -15px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: transparent url('fancybox.png') -40px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1103;
    display: none;
}
```

does anyone know how to make fancybox close button still work despite minifying css using google's minify...

without minification, everything works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image path is probably wrong, try giving it a `background:red` or something and see if it shows up.

Comment: hmm that appears to be it...is there a way to configure google's minify so as to not do that?

Comment: @kamikaze_pilot: Here: [http://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/UriRewriting](http://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/UriRewriting)